# How to prevent audio generation loss in python?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, pydub

I have a script that needs to run audio through ffmpeg and pydub multiple times each. I realized that by the end of all this the audio sounds a bit muffled compared to the original. What steps can I take to make sure the quality is as high as possible at the end? I'm going from mp3/m4b to wav btw.

Comment: Need to see what you're doing to be able to make any suggestions.

Comment: every time you re-encode mp3 you're going to have quality loss - if you want to avoid it you'll need to use lossless codecs throughout the process, try flac if you can. if not, wav will work (though it produces much larger files)